# How does the Acrobatics long jump work with a double move action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The [Acrobatics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics) skill states "No jump can allow you to exceed your maximum movement for the round."

To me this sounds like you can get your double movement out of the jump.  For example, a character with a speed of 30 ft could get a running start (10 ft) and then jump a 30 ft gap and still have 20 ft of movement left from his second move action.

Is that correct?  Would it need 2 Acrobatics checks or is it all done with the one check?

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that jumping a 30 ft gap would beat the current world record long jump (29' 4 1/4")? And that's without wearing heavy armor, carrying a heavy pack, or killing monsters every day.

Comment: haha nice!  that made me laugh.  Although, to be fair, these adventurers are rather extraordinary and they can use abilities far beyond our own capabilities.

Comment: DC for a 30 foot jump is only DC 30?  And only requires 10 feet of running first?   Totally doable!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is indeed correct, you can double-move jump in order to cover longer distances. I would expect the result of the jump distance to be determined in a single skill check. A double-move does not make the result higher, but is required if you happen to have a very high roll, or more often because you have used up a fair amount of your first move action getting to the point where you want to start the jump.

Other skill checks might be required e.g. to maintain balance if the landing surface was tricky, or if the rolled distance ended up short of target and the character needed to grab a ledge. However, you wouldn't need a second acrobatics check for the same jump.

Comment: I thought jumping was a standard action. I was wrong. -- "Action: None. An Acrobatics check is made as part of another action or as a reaction to a situation." Cool